# how to disable all animations and effects for jQuery Overlay?

Tags: jquery, animation, overlay

I'm using [jQueryOverlay](http://jquerytools.org/documentation/overlay/index.html) for something I'm working on and I want to disable animations and effects. Now (the default behavior) seems to move from bottom-right to center of the screen, I want that off. Just to appear simple on the center of the screen. I set speed to '0' but still, the animation remains.
Is there any property to disable animations?

Comment: You are able to create your custom effect. http://jquerytools.org/documentation/tooltip/index.html#effects just only add `.show()`

Answer (score 0):

There is a method to disable all effects from jquery :

```
 jQuery.fx.off = true;
```

Maybe there is such an extension in the overlay object ?